# Mapping from a pair or names to a value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have an application where I have a set of named nodes.  For each pair of nodes, I want to store their connectivity value.  The nodes will come and go over time, so I cannot initialize an "array" for the start.  The names are not sequential integers, but arbitrary object IDs or string names.

I need to be able to do:

```
lookup(name1, name2) -> value
```

And also

```
set(name1, name2, value)
```

And, when a new node joins, to do:

```
set(newname, [all other nodes], default_value)
```

The assumption is that for each pair, the direction does not matter. I.e., (name1,name2) should have the same value as (name2,name1).

The most obvious Python implementation of this seems to be a two-level dictionary:

```
{ name1 : { name2: value, name3:value}, name2: {name1:value, name3:value}, ... etc. }
```

Is that the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**

The proposal to use a dict with pairs as keys is probably better inside of Python. However, I also turned out to have a side contraint to be able to export and import the data set as a list of lists (in order to support serialization of the state inside the Simics simulator) - and for that the two-level map was very natural.  But I guess the pair would have worked there too.  Hard to tell what is better, actually.

Comment: This data structure looks a lot like a graph, though a graph might be overkill for your application. Take a look at networkx or igraph...

Comment: It is a graph, but a fully connected one, so a general graph is probably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `frozenset()` keys:

```
{frozenset([name1, name2]): value, frozenset([name2, name3]): other_value}
```

The advantage is that `frozenset()` objects can be used as keys, *and* the order of the nodes doesn't matter; `frozenset([name1, name2])` is equal to `frozenset([name2, name1])`.

To get a list of all nodes, you'd have to use:

```
all_nodes = reduce(frozenset.union, yourdict.keys())
```

If this is Python 2, use `yourdict.iterkeys()` instead. From where you can then produce all possible combinations to set a default value with:

```
from itertools import permutations:

for name1, name2 in permutations(all_nodes, r=2):
    key = frozenset([name1, name2])
    if key not in yourdict:
        yourdict[key] = default_value
```

Alternatively, if you wrap the whole structure in a class (probably a good idea), you can add an additional index that tracks nodes used as well, keeping this index up-to-date as you update the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use dictionary with tuples as keys

```
{(name1, name2) : value, (name1, name3) : value, (name2, name1) : value, ...}
```

instead of

```
{name1 : {name2 : value, name3 : value}, name2 : {name1 : value, ...}, ... etc.}
```

Then operations will be look like the following:

```
values = {(name1, name2) : value, (name1, name3) : value, (name2, name1) : value, ...}

def lookup(name1, name2):
    return values[name1, name2]

def set(name1, name2, value):
    values[name1, name2] = value
    values[name2, name1] = value  # for symmetry
```

**P.S.** Not to waste memory for the default connectivity values you can modify lookup like following:

```
def lookup(name1, name2):
   return values.get((name1, name2), default_value)
```

But in this case you will get `default_value` for the nodes not in a set.

Comment: But this won't handle `(name2, name1)` being the same as `(name1, name2)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if we use just defined `lookup` and `set` operations there will be no difference from outside point of view. Of course fronzensets still can be used to halve used memory.

Comment: This would most likely have worked just as well as what I did; but the end result is syntactically very similar. I get foo[name1][name2] instead of foo[name1,name2].

Comment: @jakobengblom2, but in this case it's easier to handle nonexistent node names.